# Is a function $f(x)=\ln({x^2-1})$ even and symmetric

Tags: real-analysis, functions, real-numbers, symmetry, even-and-odd-functions

We have a function:
$$ 
f(x)=\ln(x^2-1) 
$$
The function is symmetric because: $D_f=(-\infty,-1) \ \cup\ (1,\infty)$
I understand this as if we would multipy this by $-1$ we would get the same $D_f$

I don't quite understand the following:

EDIT* $$g(x)=\ln(x-1)+\ln(x+1)=\ln((x-1)(x+1))=\ln(x^2-1)$$

Now, this function is not symmetric, because the domain of this function is only $D_g=(1,\infty)$. So because of that its also not an even function.

But why is that so since the way I see it: $g(x)=f(x)$? How can both functions have different domains? Do I understand the theory behind symmetry and even, odd functions correctly?

Symmetry as I written in my notes is: $D \subseteq \mathbb R $ is symmetric if: EDIT** $$ x \in D \implies -x \in D$$

Comment: What does symmetric mean?

Comment: maybe the domain of $\ln(x-1)+\ln(x+1)$ is only $(1,\infty)$, but the domain of $\ln((x-1)(x+1))$ should include $(-\infty,-1)$

Comment: Surely that is always true?

Comment: @BiliDebili,  symmetric with respect to what? Your definition doesn't hold because: $$\forall x\in\langle -\infty, 1\rangle\;x\land-x\in D$$ Furthermore, use: \mathbb R

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes, but isn't $\ln(x-1)+\ln(x+1)=\ln((x-1)(x+1))$

Comment: @BiliDebili:  they're equal when they're defined; for comparison, $\frac xx=1$ when $x\ne0$

Comment: Fairly sure the definition of a symmetric function ought to be: $x \in D \implies -x \in D$.

Comment: @fGDu94 Thank you, I will edit the question

Comment: I have just made up this idea myself, but convince yourself it makes sense

Comment: @fGDu94 Yes it makes sense since if we would have negative values in the negative domain the elements are the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless explicitly restricted, the domain of $$g(x)=\ln((x-1)(x+1))$$ 
is
$$D_g=(-\infty,-1) \ \cup\ (1,\infty).$$

$f$ and $g$ are rigorously the same.

---

**Update:**

The question was changed after this answer.

In the new version,

$$f(x)\ne g(x).$$